# Scikit-fuzzy output does not return full result

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I'm implementing the tipping example for scikit-fuzzy library as it is given in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem.html). Code generates a tip percentage of %20 for the given quality (6.5/10) and service (9.8/10) levels.
But the problem is when I change both levels to 10/10 I get the result 21.0, and 4.3 if I change both to 0. So although the min-max tip levels are defined as [0-25] percent the result range is between [4.3-21] %.
Is there something wrong or is this just the nature of fuzzy logic: "Always leave a tip, but no more than %21" ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.